# Able to connect to schema thru sql plus but not thru sql developer

Tags: database, oracle11g, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello to all oracle database experts,

I logged in on sqlplus as sysdba and run a script that creates a schema (tables, procedures, etc) and it was a success.

I run a simple query: SELECT username FROM all_users ORDER BY username; and was able to see that the username was indeed created.

Now, I went to sql developer and created a connection using the newly created username but I cannot make a connection (making sure that my username, password, hostname, port and sid are correct). I repeated the query to see if I can see the newly created user but it is no longer showing.

So, why do you guys think what happened why I can see the users when I ran a query on sqlplus and not on sql developer? (both queries were run using the sysdba connection)

Thanks for those who will give their 2 cents

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Does your new user have CREATE SESSION privilege? if no you need to grant it: GRANT CREATE SESSION TO <schema name>;